# Cannot use (type []map[string]interface {}) as type []string in field value

Tags: go, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

How to store Array of JSONs (in string format) in []string (individual JSON string in each index of string array) ?

```
package main
import (
 "encoding/json"
 "fmt"
)
type StructData struct {
  Data      []string `json:"data"`
}

func main() {
 empArray := "[{\"abc\":\"abc\"},{\"def\":\"def\"}]"

 var results []map[string]interface{}

 json.Unmarshal([]byte(empArray), &results)

 pr := &StructData{results}
 prAsBytes, err := json.Marshal(pr)
 if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error :", err)
 }
}
```

Here I am getting the error

```
cannot use results (type []map[string]interface {}) as type []string in field value
```

Is there any other method to store the each json string data in each index of string array?

Comment: `StructData.Data` is a field of type `[]string`. How could you set (assign) a map (`results`) to it?

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Comment: I want to store individual json string in each index of string array. My approach may be wrong by assigning []map[string]interface {} to [] string! Is there any method to do?

Comment: Maybe you want `Data []json.RawMessage`?

Comment: So, how to convert empArray to that format?

Comment: @VenkateshS Is this what you looking for https://play.golang.com/p/SSEsADYyqOC? Or do you want the individual json *objects* to be turned into json strings?

Answer (score 2):

One of the gotchas of unmarshaling JSON to a map is that it only goes 1 level deep: that is, if you have nested JSON, it will only unmarshal the first level of your data structure. This means you'll need to not only iterate through your map `results` but you'll also need to build whatever datatype you need for `&StructData{}`. This would look something like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type StructData struct {
    Data []string `json:"data"`
}

func main() {
    empArray := "[{\"abc\":\"abc\"},{\"def\":\"def\"}]"

    var results []map[string]interface{}

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(empArray), &results)

    // create a new variable that we'll use as the input to StructData{}
    var unpacked []string

    // iterate through our results map to get the 'next level' of our JSON
    for _, i := range results {
        // marshal our next level as []byte
        stringified, err := json.Marshal(i)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error :", err)
        }
        // add item to our unpacked variable as a string
        unpacked = append(unpacked, string(stringified[:]))
    }
    pr := &StructData{unpacked}
    prAsBytes, err := json.Marshal(pr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error :", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(prAsBytes[:]))
}
```